# How to add 'html element' to the view from rails controller?

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm working with Nokogiri (*which it doesn't have good doc*) scrapping links and content from Reddit.

#### Here is my view in haml

```
%h1 Giri with Rails
%p
  Read top Current headlines about #{link_to "Rails on Reddit", 'http://www.reddit.com/r/rails/'}
%ul.list-group
  - @link.each do |url|
    = link_to url[:href], target: '_', class: "list-group-item" do
      %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-globe
      #{url[:content]}
```

Which renders like so:
[image]

#### Here is the logic/model behind that:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

class RedditScraper

  def initialize
    @headline = []
  end

  def search
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.reddit.com/r/rails/"))        
    doc.css('a.title').each do |link|
      if link['href'].include?('http')
        @headline << { content: link.content, href: link['href']}
      else
        @headline << { content: link.content, href: "http://reddit.com" + link['href'] }
      end

    end
    @headline
  end
end
```

#### And here is our skinny controller:

```
class   SearchController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @link = RedditScraper.new.search
    end
end
```

Right now as you see in the image, I'm adding `%span.glyphicon.glyphicon-link` to my view and it displays with all links. But since there are few links are related to Reddit it self and not external link, I want to change that icon ( and add extra style such as bold links or color...).

I have tried to do that within Model like so:

```
icon =   "<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link"></span>" 
@headline << { content: link.content + icon, href: link['href']}
```

But it didn't work. I want to add that extra  based on links type.

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier just to have a simple if statement in the view?

Comment: @Iceman I know what you mean and I agree in terms of simplicity. But I'm trying to keep view without any logic.

Comment: So you want to move the view logic from the view (where it should be) into the controller or model (where it shouldn't be)? Don't do this.

Comment: @sevenseacat, mmmm, make sense. I like to have my view simple without logic or with minimal when I can. So current solution is not "perforable". Then what is best 'good design' or 'good practice' to solve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying for purity, I'd add `class` field to `@link` entries, render `link_to` with that class, and provide both colours and icons through CSS. (`:before` is so cool.)